# How to set apache spark config to run in cluster mode as a databricks job

Tags: apache-spark, databricks

I have developed an Apache Spark app, compiled it into a jar and I want to run it as a Databricks job. So far I have been setting `master=local` to test. What should I set this property or others in the spark config for it to run in cluster mode in databricks. Note that I do not have a cluster created in Databricks, I only have a job that will run on demand so I do not have the url of the master node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the databricks job, you do not need to set master to anything.

You will need to do following:

```
val spark = SparkSession.builder().getOrCreate()
```